# How to scaffold a vue project in an existing repo?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

My workflow is:

1. New Github repository using GitHub website
2. Code > Open with GitHub Desktop > Clone
3. Open in Visual Studio Code

How do I use `vue create` that does **not** create a subfolder in my project folder? I want the scaffold created by `vue create` to be my project root.

Comment: Since you're creating a new Github repo and initialising a Vue app inside of it, it will be nested. Not sure what could be done in the fastest approach to strip one level while keeping the hidden `.git` directory but you should probably change the order of some things in your workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your root folder, type

- vue create .
- select Y for "Generate project in current directory"

Follow the rest of the setup and you're cool.

Answer (score 0):

Super simple steps to have a basic Vue app workflow:

- (`npm install --global @vue/cli` to install the CLI if not already done)
- `vue create my-tasty-project`, choose a default Vue preset
- `cd my-tasty-project`
- go to [`repo.new`](https://repo.new/) to create a new Github repo, set the name to `my-tasty-project`, click on `Create repository`
- copy the 3 commands given at `or push an existing repository from the command line` into your terminal
- (go to your `Github Desktop` app and click on `Add an Existing Repository from your Hard Drive...` (or `Add Existing Repository...` if you have something already opened up), select the freshly created `my-tasty-project` directory and `Add Repository` to have the whole Git flow into your GUI
- `code .`

---

I recommend the following setup:

- `npm init vue my-cool-project` (using Vue3, because we're soon in June 2022 and because it's the default recommendation)
- `cd my-cool-project`
- [ni](https://github.com/antfu/ni) (then choose `yarn`)
- `git init && gaa && gcmsg "init"` (create a new git repo + add all the files + create a new commit with the message `init`, thanks to [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh))
- [`hub create`](https://github.com/github/hub) (cool CLI tool to make some quick and simple operations on Github from the CLI, will push the local git repo remotely and link the original remote URL for you, the official [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/) could also be used)
- `code .` (may need an extra config to work on MacOS)

That way, you have your repo linked to the project and you're ready to code with some nice `gcmsg + ggpush` combo. Of course, some [`ntl`](https://github.com/netlify/cli) could be nice too, to ship apps quickly to Netlify.

Comment: I don't know, this is kind of crazy too. Workflows need fewer steps to init a project, not more. Let's call it WX.. Workflow experience.

Comment: @Dshiz this whole detailed workflow could be aliased to a single custom bash script, and be working exactly the same with just `scafovue my-cool-project` since everything happens in the CLI. If you really need fewer steps.

Comment: I really just want `vue create` to let me choose instead of being opinionated. Never heard of `scafovue`

Comment: @Dshiz `could be aliased` + `custom bash script` > `scafovue`. `scacofue` could be a custom made alias. Here, `npm init vue` is not opinionated, just the workflow of hosting, pushing and opening the project is done for you, this looks quite okay as an opinion regarding your question IMO. This could even be linked to Raycast/Alfred to a 5s fully-ready to code Vue project scaffold.

Comment: TBH, I have no idea what you're talking about. I'm trying to fit Vue into a workflow I have, and it doesn't fit. You're adding more complexity, which reduces flexibility and adoptability. To each their own though. You're clearly a Vue expert. I am not. Just trying to use/learn it and fit it in.

Comment: @Dshiz I've updated my answer with something super simple.

Comment: I do NOT want to use the git command line.

Comment: @Dshiz once the project is setup, you can open it with `Github Desktop` and continue to use the GUI without any issue. Just a matter of preference but it's exactly the same. Updated answer.

Comment: With `vue create` it's super simple, but with the workflow I described in my question, it requires many steps. Why can't I follow the workflow I describe in my question and run `vue create` inside my project?

Comment: `vue create` does not allow for such option. As you can [see here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create), the only interesting options could have been `-f` and `--merge` but they are still creating a brand new directory if they are already into another parent directory. So, your workflow of "destructuring" the scaffold into a parent directory is just **not** possible. I've given some leads on how to achieve something similar with fewer/simpler steps. Now, you need to adapt a few things if you want your project to behave properly without using the terminal at all. @dsh

Comment: I just want Vue to be the application for a new GitHub repo.

Comment: @Dshiz AFAIK, even `vue ui` does not grant a simpler approach to link a Vue app to a Github repo. The `Super simple steps to have a basic Vue app workflow` that I've described above cannot be really simpler and I looked for a tool doing that but with no success. I recommend you to practice a bit of terminal to understand what all the commands are doing (you don't really need to tbh, just follow the written instructions that I gave). You could also clone a default template, even tho this is less flexible. Otherwise, if you want fewer steps: learn + create a small bash script named `scafovue`.

Comment: Thanks for the dialog. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Dshiz I think that I am quite patient and thoughtful here regarding your question/conditions. Not sure how what I've said is anyhow related to a framework in particular or a job security. I even gave you a terminal approach at first, the most agnostic and sustainable approach regarding long term. I'm not sure how I could help you more here, which cards you'd like from me but everything listed above is mainly universal UNIX knowledge and fully agnostic (works for React, Astro or even a project done from scratch). This is not moving anytime soon, for sure.

Comment: The question I asked is still not answered. It is more steps.